# Custom ListView not getting updated

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm developing a currency exchange app and I'm having some problems with updating my ListView after extracting the rates from an API.

[image]

Ignore the flags, I just put whatever files I had to test the solution

On the start of my activity, I am defining:

```
    final ArrayList<ItemData> list = new ArrayList<ItemData>();
    final String[] web = {
            "EUR", "JPY", "USD", "GBP"
    };
    final Integer[] imageId = {R.drawable.austria, R.drawable.bangladesh, R.drawable.benin, R.drawable.uk};
    private static String _spinnerData;
    public static String test;

    public static synchronized String getCurrentSpinner(){
        if (_spinnerData == null) {
String _spinnerData;
        }
        return _spinnerData;
    }
```

And onCreate() is defined as:

```
... not important ... 

  Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_complist);
        final SpinnerAdapter adapter1 = new SpinnerAdapter(this,
                R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.txt, list);
        spin.setAdapter(adapter1);


        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                ItemData item = (ItemData) (parentView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                Log.i("item_1", item.getText());
                String spinnerData = getCurrentSpinner();
                spinnerData = item.getText();
            }
```

I then have a custom Adapter to put the flags+name, where the name is a textview.

Afterwards, I get my conversion rate from an API, through a function getRate() that is working. 
On the custom adapter, I have overriden the getView method:

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null, true);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

            String currency;
            txtTitle.setText(web[position]);
            String spinnerData= getCurrentSpinner();
            if (spinnerData!=null) {


                currency=spinnerData;
                getRate(currency, web[position], txtTitle);

            }

            return rowView;
        }
```

So, in getRate I obtain a String from each row of the ListView and replace it by the value in another coin.

My problem is: If I write getRate("EUR",web[position],txtTitle), everything works as intended.

[image]

However, if I put the code as it is, it just doesn't update my ListView. I put a breakpoint and currency is "EUR", so it should be equivalent to what I had by hardcoding the string.

I think that probably the ListView isn't getting properly updated, or the function is making some callback that is replacing my TextViews with the original values.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I have a blog about listview: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/ In the sample for Array Adapter, it also use spinner to update the list view. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some problems with the flow of the data in your Activity.

The getView in the listview should return a view with the populated data from a data source that has the data.
I would advice changing to have something like:

Snippet position selected -> call web API to get any data that you need -> when is returned add it to a list of data that is being displayed on the listview -> then call in the adapter of the listview notifyDataSetChanged()

I would recommend this article for more information about using listviews: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: This solved it - I  think the problem was that I was trying to update my adapter at the same time I was acquiring data. I had to use threads to wait for the data to get collected, then populate the adapter and refresh the view.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Two things stand out to me.

First, this block:

```
public static synchronized String getCurrentSpinner(){
    if (_spinnerData == null) {
        String _spinnerData;
    }
    return _spinnerData;
}
```

This doesn't really make sense. It reads "if the static scoped `_spinnerData` is null, create another locally scoped String also called `_spinnerData` and do nothing with it, then return the statically scoped instance."

And second, this logic:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    ItemData item = (ItemData) (parentView.getItemAtPosition(position));
    Log.i("item_1", item.getText());
    String spinnerData = getCurrentSpinner();
    spinnerData = item.getText();
}
```

This reads "create a temporary string called `spinnerData` that is initialized with the return value of `getCurrentSpinner()` then immediately replace it with the value of `item.getText()` then throw the whole thing away (because it's never used thereafter)".

It appears to me you have a misunderstanding in how references work. I *think* what you are trying to do is save the current spinner selection and use that in your `getView()`.

If that's the case, you would do something like this:

```
private String _spinnerData; // Does not need to be static

// In onItemSelected
ItemData item = (ItemData) (parentView.getItemAtPosition(position));
Log.i("item_1", item.getText());
_spinnerData = item.getText(); // Save the last item selected

// In getView()
// Call this method with the last known spinner selection
getRate(_spinnerData, web[position], txtTitle);
```

I would have to assume you are new to Java and don't fully understand how references and scope work. Is that a fair assumption? If so, I strongly suggest you take a step back from Android and work on getting more familiar and comfortable with Java before proceeding. Android is complicated enough without having to figure out the language as you go as well.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I am fairly new to Java, I'm more used to other OOP languages like C++! I previously tried what you suggested and inside getView() _spinnerData is being returned as null (it crashes the app if I try to print it before my if condition), that's why I attemped what I described in my post

Comment: If this didn't answer your questions or solve your problem, please post a clearer explanation of what is not working (beyond "it just doesn't update the ListView" and maybe include the code for `getRate`)